Write CSV from Nested anonymous object
I didn't succeed to write a CSV for the following structure, I'm pretty sure it should be possible automatically but I'm missing something...
The _recordedData variable is a dictionary of List<RecordSample> such as the data property of the RecordedSample for a specific key of the dictionary will always be the same.
For example, _recordedData["eulerAngle"] would return a List<RecordSample> where the data property of each RecordSample is an EulerAnglesMessage struct.
But when I'm trying to export each List<RecordSample> of the dictionary in the ExportRecordedData() method, the resulting csv file doesn't contain the property of the data struct.
I don't know what I'm missing to make it work...
Thanks a lot for your help !
private static Dictionary<string, List<RecordSample>> _recordedData = new Dictionary<string, List<RecordSample>>();

private class RecordSample
{
    public double record_time_ms { get; set; } // The elapsed time in ms since the beginning of the recording
    public string record_id; // A string identifier to identify the sensors device at the origin of the record
    public object data { get; set; } // The data being recorded
}

public struct EulerAnglesMessage
{
    public UInt64 timestamp { get; set; }
    public float roll { get; set; }
    public float pitch { get; set; }
    public float yaw { get; set; }
}

public struct QuaternionMessage
{
    public UInt64 timestamp { get; set; }
    public float w { get; set; }
    public float x { get; set; }
    public float y { get; set; }
    public float z { get; set; }
}

private static void ExportRecordedData()
{
    foreach (string key in _recordedData.Keys)
    {
        string path = $"{export_path}\\{key}.csv";
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                 csv.WriteRecords(_recordedData[key]);
             }
        }
    }
}


To do it using only CsvWriter, without modifying classes or other, you need to manually write headers and each row. But it is not that hard, as you can see in below code example:
using CsvHelper;
using System.Globalization;

const string export_path = "test.csv";

var data = new List<RecordData>();
data.Add(new RecordData());
data.Add(new RecordData());
data.Add(new RecordData());

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(export_path))
{
    using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        // First write header
        csv.WriteHeader(data[0].GetType());
        csv.WriteHeader(data[0].Value.GetType());
        csv.NextRecord();
        // Then write each row
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            csv.WriteRecord(item);
            csv.WriteRecord(item.Value);

            // Remember to start new record at the end!
            csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }
}

public class RecordData
{
    public double Time { get; set; } = 42;
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public object Value { get; set; } = new Data();
}

public class Data
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string Prop2 { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}


Nice ! Exactly what I was looking for, tested and it's working great ! Wasn't clear in the docs you could do that.

The problem is that when you try to write the dictionary’s data to a CSV, CsvWriter only sees the RecordSample properties directly. It doesn’t know how to dig into the data property, which can be a EulerAnglesMessage or QuaternionMessage.
To fix this, you’ll need to "flatten" the structure that is, pull out the relevant fields from the data property and include them when writing to the CSV. The easiest way to handle this is by transforming each RecordSample into a simpler, flat object that contains everything you want in the CSV.
Here's a solution that should do the trick:
    private static void ExportRecordedData()
{
    foreach (var key in _recordedData.Keys)
    {
        var path = $"{export_path}\\{key}.csv";
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            var flattenedRecords = _recordedData[key]
                .Select(sample => FlattenSample(sample))
                .ToList();

            csv.WriteRecords(flattenedRecords);
        }
    }
}

// Flattens RecordSample by pulling out data fields based on its type.
private static object FlattenSample(RecordSample sample)
{
    return sample.data switch
    {
        EulerAnglesMessage euler => new
        {
            sample.record_time_ms,
            sample.record_id,
            DataType = "EulerAngles",
            euler.timestamp,
            euler.roll,
            euler.pitch,
            euler.yaw
        },
        QuaternionMessage quaternion => new
        {
            sample.record_time_ms,
            sample.record_id,
            DataType = "Quaternion",
            quaternion.timestamp,
            quaternion.w,
            quaternion.x,
            quaternion.y,
            quaternion.z
        },
        _ => new
        {
            sample.record_time_ms,
            sample.record_id,
            DataType = "Unknown"
        }
    };
}

Basically what we are doing here is
Flattening the data:
Since the data field can contain different types (like EulerAnglesMessage or QuaternionMessage), we use a switch expression to figure out what type of data we’re dealing with. Once we know the type, we pull out its individual fields (like roll, pitch, or w, x, etc.) and bundle everything into an anonymous object.
Unknown data:
If you ever add other message types in the future, the switch will fall back to a basic object with "Unknown" as the DataType.
Write to CSV:
Now that each RecordSample is converted into a flat structure, the CsvWriter can handle it easily and write everything to the CSV without issues.

Thanks for the detailed answer ! Yeah I was afraid I had to do something like that. The issue is I have way more type of data messages than the 2 shown here, so I guess I'll have to use reflection to dynamically flatten the RecordSample object based on the type of data. Problem is I might loose a lot of performance as I've been told reflection can be slow...

Glad the answer helped! Yeah, reflection can get slow, especially with lots of data types. A better approach might be to use interfaces. If all your messages (like EulerAnglesMessage) implement a common interface (e.g., IMessageData), you can access their properties without reflection. Or, if performance is critical, you could write some helper methods to manually flatten each type, more upfront work, but faster in the long run!
